# WSDL generated type does not take COM attributes

Tags: c#, com, vb6, wsdl

I have a WSDL generated class

```
 [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class FVZServicesClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<FVZScanningDocumentInfo.FVZServices.FVZServices>, FVZScanningDocumentInfo.FVZServices.FVZServices {
...
}
```

I need to provide a library that is used in VB6. I use a COM Interface which happens to use the above class.

When I register the assembly with

```
regasm MyAssembly.dll /tlb:MyAssembly.tlb
```

I get the error message

> Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version
>   4.7.3062.0 for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.3062.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Types registered successfully Type library exporter warning processing
>   'MyAssembly.FVZServices.FVZServicesClient, MyAssembly'. Warning: Type
>   library exporter encountered a type that derives from a generic class
>   and is not marked as [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]. Class
>   interfaces cannot be exposed for such types. Consider marking the type
>   with [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] and exposing an
>   explicit interface as the default interface to COM using the
>   ComDefaultInterface attribute. Assembly exported to
>   'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\ScanLibrary\Packet\MyAssembly.tlb', and the
>   type library was registered successfully

When I add the Attribute `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]` as suggested to FVZServicesClient, I still get the same error message the next time I try the regasm. I know that the generated code can be overwritten at any time, but I verified with DotPeek that the ClassInterface-attribute was still in the compiled code.

Another thing I tried, was to create a partial class of FVZServicesClient that had the ClassInterface-attribute. I also marked the default interface with COMDefaultInterface as the message suggests. The result was the same. Adding the Attribute `[ComVisible(false)]` for the FVZServicesClient did not help either.

When the library is referenced in VB6, the compile results in an error: "User-defined type not defined".

How can I exclude FVZServicesClient from the COM interface?

Comment: If your WSDL generated code was in VB.net rather than C#, you could try changing the `Public` declaration to `Friend` or `Friend Protected`, then perhaps the generated code wouldn't be included in the exported interface. Can't tell if that would be allowable with the small amount of code posted. Unfortunately, there's no matching declaration in C# to VB's `Friend`. Can you use VB.net instead of C# for this generated class (and associated code)?

Comment: I tried to generate the WSDL generated code as internal in C#. It made no difference. No VB.net is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was deceiving. In FVZServicesClient there is a method that expects a parameter to be passed by reference.

```
public ScanBatchItemType[] CheckBatch(ref ScanBatchItemType[] scanBatchItemTypes)
```

I did not pass it by ref. Once I corrected that, the error message disappeared. At the moment there is no COMVisibility or ClassInterface Attribute on FVZServicesClient and COM is Ok with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute `[ComVisible(false)]` to `class FVZServicesClient`.

I'm not sure how your code generation process works, but as noted in the question you can at least try adding this manually and seeing if it has the desired effect.

Comment: I did try this already before I posted the question. It made no difference.